# Catch Event or something when page adds/loads new images?

Tags: javascript, image, events, dom, load

When the website first loads i easily iterate through all images with $('img')
But if the website loads new images, especially like google/bing image search, is there some way to catch an event for that or something in order to handle those images too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DOM mutation observer to detect when a new `<img>` element is added. See [this MDN post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) for more details. You'll want to look for the `addedNodes` property of the `MutationRecord` object.

Comment: Thanks! document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted"... was what i was looking for :)

Comment: Note that DOMNodeInserted is deprecated, because of performance issues: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/L0Lx11u5Bvs. But it will work for now.

Comment: deprecated meaning it gets replaced by something faster or that the performance issue will get fixed? The Google forum thread you linked does not provide an alternative. What can i use instead?

Comment: The mutation observers (in the MDN post I linked to) are the alternative. 'deprecated' means that mutation *events* like `DOMNodeInserted` will get removed at some point in the future.